# How to create real time email validator for subscribe button?

Tags: email-validation, subscribe

I want to create a subscribe button for my website, which validates the email in real time for valid or invalid email addresses. how to create it or is there any open source service available for this?

Comment: You can send a mail and deal with the mail error codes too.

Answer (score 2):

I actually run a SaaS that does exactly this at [https://clicktoverify.net/](https://clicktoverify.net). Basically all you need to do is drop in a JS file on your front-end. The service will send a verification email to your user, and then call a Javascript callback of your choice when they click the verification link.

If you sign up and send me an email (it's in the welcome email) I can help you with the integration.